# MATLAB: How can I reorder this vector?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a column vector A.

I want to reorder A into a new column vector B, which should be organized as follows, taking each 12th element:

[Element 1, 13, 25, ... then 2, 14, 26, ..., 3, 15, 27,  and so on]

I can make a start with the following code

```
B = A(1:12:length(A))
```

I could keep doing that and appending to B. However, I suspect there's a better way to do this without repeating that code twelve times.

Comment: Use `reshape`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: You could use two nested `for loop` to obtain the answer from a fix number of calls. 
`A = 1:1:144;
B = zeros(size(A));
for ii = 1:size(A,2)/12;
     for kk = 1:12;
          B(ii + (kk-1)*12) = A(kk+(ii-1)*12);
     end;
end;`

Comment: @SimoJoe A loop is newer bad of course, but your solution could be vectorized to reduce the number of loops with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Davids comment (which gives a good suggestion, but is a bit obscure). You can use reshape to create a matrix where the rows have the shape you want `[1,13,15, ...; 2,14,26, ...; ...]`. You can then transpose the matrix and rebuild it using reshape again. The example is in a bit smaller scale with a vector of length 24 and shorter permutation `[1,9,17,2,10,18, ...]` (steps of 8).

```
a = 1:24
q = reshape(a,8,3)
r = q.'
b = reshape(r,1,24)
```

Note here that you may need to pad with zeros in case the number of elements is in the vector is not M*N.

Following the example you will also show you that Matlab works columnwise, which is probably the most important thing you will learn here. Using that knowledge you will be able to write much more effective Matlab code in the future.